# GZIP Compression help. Can't get it to work (2)

Tags: .htaccess, optimization, compression, gzip, pagespeed

I am working on my site speed optmization. I am having problems with gzip compression. I put the code in the `.htaccess` file, upload it to online and it does not work. When I check with this tool http://www.gidnetwork.com/tools/gzip-test.php it says `page content is not compressed`. Also I check it with gtmetrix.com and still no luck.

Here is the code I put in my `.htaccess` file:

```
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript
</IfModule>
```

I also tryied without the `<IfModule mod_deflate.c></IfModule>`:

```
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript
```

Also tried this method in my htaccess:

```
<files *.html>
    SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
</files>
```

Still no luck. Am I doing something wrong? Please help if you can!

Answer (score 0):

For Gzipping behaviour your assets, try this one.

```
<FilesMatch "\.(html|php|htm|xml|txt|xsl)$">

    <IfModule mod_expires.c>

     Header set Cache-Control "max-age=7200, must-revalidate"

     Header append Vary Accept-Encoding

     Header append Accept-Encoding "gzip"

    </IfModule>

    </FilesMatch>
```

Comment: that did not help. Still same problem

Comment: I would suggest you to have a look on https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/best-practices/payload#GzipCompression